# iOS UIScrollView ページング幅の設定方法

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

UIScrollViewを利用してページングできるメニューの作成を考えていますがページングの幅の設定方法がわかりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
機種
iPhone6

スクロール幅は375/3の125にし、一回のページングで1つメニューが隣にずれるようにしたいと考えています。
ページングを行うためScrollViewの"Paging Enabled"をYESに設定しました。
現在ScrollView上に幅625のviewを設置しその上にさらに「赤・青・緑・赤・青」の順で幅125のビューを配置してスライドメニューを作成しようとしています。
[このリンク先](http://www.hirano-dept.com/blog/2011/08/iphone-uiscrollviewpaging.html)にScrollViewのboundsがスクロール幅を決めていると情報がありましたのでviewDidLoadを下記のように実装しました。

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // testMenuViewのサイズは(625, 30)
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.testMenuView.frame.size;
    // scrollViewのboundsでスクロール幅を設定?
    self.scrollView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 30);
}
```

しかし、ページングの幅はなぜか250となりました。
ScrollViewのboundsの行をコメントアウトしてもページングの幅は250から変化せず
2つ分メニューがずれてしまいます。

ページングの幅はどのように設定できるでしょうか？
もし分かる方いましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ビューのサイズ設定は、`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`メソッド内で行ってください。これより前に呼ばれるメソッドたとえば`viewDidLoad()`メソッドでは、いろいろな理由（たとえば、画面の向きが縦か横かとか）で、レイアウトが再設定されることがあるので、完全にレイアウトが確定した後で、プログラマのサイズ指定をしないといけません。